# How to redirect to a custom page based on IP

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a web app build using react on the front end and c# on the back end.

Is it possible to block access to a given range of IP's? (basically routing those requests to a custom 403 page)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do with react but you can achieve this with the help of nginx or apache application server.

Answer (score 0):

Using react and the libraries react-public-ip and ip-range-check we can do something like this:

```
const publicIp = require('react-public-ip')
const ipv4 = await publicIp.v4() || ''

const ipRangeCheck = require('ip-range-check')
const validIp = ipRangeCheck(ipv4, ['103.88.125.0/20', '99.118.72.122'])

if (!validIp) {
  return(<>You are in the wrong network</>)
}
```

I  Leave the code here for future reference, but this is probably a very bad practice since it still leaves the backend unprotected.

So either doing some check in the midleware in the backend or as Ashish mention to tweak nginx or apache is a better option. (i'm strugling with those thou)